# Why do I get a wrong output of equals method?

Tags: java, equals

I am writing a code and am following all instructions given to me. All the codes and methods look fine when I run the program but the equal method! Based on the instructions, I am supposed to get false when the tested asks if point (a, b)---(c, d) is equals to (e, f)---(g, h), but I get true. Can anyone give me an idea where I am doing wrong?

```js
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       //if (obj instanceof Segment) {
           //Segment other = (Segment) obj;
           //return p1 == other.getP1() && p2 == other.getP2();
       //}
       //else {
          
           //throw new IllegalArgumentException("undefined");
       //}
      
       if(obj == null)
           return false;
       if(this == obj)
           return true;
       //if(!(obj instanceof Segment))
           //return false;
      
       else if(obj.getClass() != this.getClass())
           return false;
      
           else {
               Segment S = (Segment)obj;
       if (this.getP1() == S.getP1() &&
                   this.getP2() == S.getP2())
           return true;
      
       else if(this.getP1() != S.getP1() &&
               this.getP2() != S.getP2()){
           return true;}
      
       return false;
      
           }      
           //else if(obj.getP1() != this.getP1() &&
               //   obj.getP2() != this.getP2());
       //   return false;
      
  
   }
```

Comment: What are the return types of the methods `getP1()` and `getP2()`?  If they're object types, rather than primitives, then you should replace your `==` and `!=` comparisons with calls to their `equals` methods.

Comment: Why use getters at all here since you're in the class itself? Just use `p1` and `S.p1` instead of `this.getP1()` and `S.getP1()`; also, you have a lot of redundant `else` -- why `else` when you `return`?

Comment: You can just have one boolean variable that changes values depending on condition and return that variable (instead of having multiple `return` statements).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
else if (this.getP1() == S.getP1() && this.getP2() == S.getP2())
  return true;
else if(this.getP1() != S.getP1() && this.getP2() != S.getP2())
  return true;
```

These tests basically returns true if both points of the two segments are equal or they are both different to each respective other.

This is redundant and wrong since it would return `true` for, for example, `(10,20)` and `(30,40)`.

You just need to return the first condition as the result, eg:

```
return this.getP1() == S.getP1() && this.getP2() == S.getP2();
```

Comment: I changed it but still same output. :(

Comment: Ava, If the answer didn't fix your problem, you shouldn't have clicked the tick.  When other potential respondents see the tick, they won't bother supplying a new answer.  The tick means "this worked for me, and my question needs no further attention".

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(this.getP1() != S.getP1() && this.getP2() != S.getP2()){
    return true;
}
```

for

```
if(this.getP1() != S.getP1() || this.getP2() != S.getP2())
{
    return false;
}
```

because if one of their members are diferent they are not the equals so you should return `false`